# AWS Boto / Warrant library: SRP authentication and credentials error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

I have been stuck on the following issue for quite some time now. Within Python I want users to retrieve a token based upon their username and password from the AWS cognito-identity-pool making use of srp authentication. With this token I want the users to upload data to s3.

This is part of the code I use (from the warrant library): https://github.com/capless/warrant

```
    self.client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name="us-east-1")
    response = boto_client.initiate_auth(
        AuthFlow='USER_SRP_AUTH',
        AuthParameters=auth_params,
        ClientId=self.client_id
    )


def get_auth_params(self):
    auth_params = {'USERNAME': self.username,
                   'SRP_A': long_to_hex(self.large_a_value)}
    if self.client_secret is not None:
        auth_params.update({
            "SECRET_HASH":
            self.get_secret_hash(self.username,self.client_id, self.client_secret)})
    return auth_params
```

However, I keep on getting:

```
botocore\auth.py", line 352, in add_auth raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

I was able to get rid of this error by adding credentials in the .aws/credentials file. But this is not in line with the purpose of this program. It seems like there is a mistake in the warrant or botocore library and the it keeps on attempting to use the AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key from the credentials file, rather than that the given credentials (username and password) are used.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am on to Cognito team. initiate auth is an unauthenticated call so it shouldn't require you to provide AWS credentials. The service endpoint will not validate the sigv4 signature for these calls.

That being said, some client libraries have certain peculiarities in the sense that you need to provide some dummy credentials otherwise the client library will throw an exception. However you can provide anything for the credentials.

Comment: Yes! That's it. Thanks a lot. For anyone running into a similar issue, I have used the following dummy's 
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY

Comment: I had the same problem when going with REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH sequence. Providing aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key (even though they should already be expired) solved the issue as well

Answer (score 2):

I too ran into this, using warrant.

The problem is that the boto3 libraries are trying to sign the request to aws, but this request is not supposed to be signed.  To prevent that, create the identity pool client with a config that specifies no signing.

```
import boto3
from botocore import UNSIGNED
from botocore.config import Config

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name='us-east-1', config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED))
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key are totally different from username and password.

The Boto3 client has to connect to the AWS service endpoint (in your case: `cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`) to execute any API. Before executing an API, the API credentials (key+secret) have to provided to authenticate your AWS account. Without autheticating your account, you cannot call `cognito-idp` APIs.

There is one AWS account (key/secret) but there can be multiple users (username/password).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I read the following in the boto3 documentation: "where ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY and SESSION_TOKEN are variables that contain your access key, secret key, and optional session token. Note that the examples above do not have hard coded credentials. We do not recommend hard coding credentials in your source code." Furthermore, in my android app where users (after signing up to my user pool) can also authenticate (using username and password) I never use the access key ID and secret access key and this works fine. How and why is this different between android and boto3?

Comment: Furthermore, in signers.py from botocore you can find the following comment in def get_auth_instance:  # If there's no credentials provided (i.e credentials is None), # then we'll pass a value of "None" over to the auth classes, # which already handle the cases where no credentials have # been provided. So basically, using username and password (not from AWS account but from user pool!!!) I try to retrieve temporary credentials. This way users of the program dont have to remember their access key and secret key and can identify themselves with username / password and perform AWS actions.